# スプレッドシートからのデータ読み出し

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

スプレッドシートをDB的に活用したいのです。
index.htmlの［selectindex］に値を入れて検索し、その結果を［text1］,［text2］に表示したいのですが、なかなか思うように動作しません。
どなたかお力添えをいただければ助かります。

**コード.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  var tpl = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html');
  return tpl.evaluate();

}

function SelectData( form ) {


  var SPREAD_ID = '1j5TH87Wv9Uz8KpQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5ZJKg';
  var SHEET_NAME = 'シート1';
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREAD_ID); //スプレッド取得
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);   //シート取得

  Logger.log(ss);

  //1行目1列から30行目1列まで順次確認
  for(var i = 1;i < 20;i++){
    var val = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    if ( val == form.selectindex ) {
      //2列目の値を返す
      return sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      return sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var data1=sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var date2=sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();

    }
  }

  //検索結果が無い場合
  return "not found";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>スプレッド読込みテスト</title>
<!--クライアントスクリプト-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#edit input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(eventEnd).SelectData(this.parentNode);
    });
  });
  // SelectData() が完了したら呼び出される
  function eventEnd( serverResult ) {


   //Msgを表示させる
 //window.confirm(serverResult);
   document.form1.text1.value=(serverResult);

  }
</script>

</head>

<!--本体-->
<body>
 <div id="edit">

      <form name="form1">
        <input id="selectindex" name="selectindex" type="text" value="" ><br>
        <input id="selectindex" name="text1" type="text" value="" >
        <input id="selectindex" name="text2" type="text" value="" >          
        <input id="submitbutton" name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="スプレッド内容表示" >


      </form>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` の書き方が間違っているのではないでしょうか？ 少なくとも `id` は、一つの html 内で、一意であるという規約のはずです。

`id=text1` に変更して試したところ、動きました。

```
    <form name="form1">
      <input id="selectindex" name="selectindex" type="text" value="">
      <br>
      <input id="text1" type="text" value="">
      <input id="text2" type="text" value="">
      <input id="submitbutton" name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="スプレッド内容表示">
    </form>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 追記 2016-02-08 22:15

gs 側で、複数の値を返す用に変更

```
function SelectData( form ) {
  var SPREAD_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var SHEET_NAME = 'シート1';
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREAD_ID); //スプレッド取得
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);   //シート取得

  Logger.log(ss);

  var values = [];

  //1行目1列から30行目1列まで順次確認
  for(var i = 1;i < 20;i++){
    var val = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    if ( val == form.selectindex ) {
      values.push(sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
      values.push(sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue());
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

html の js 側で、複数の値を取得するように変更

```
// SelectData() が完了したら呼び出される
function eventEnd(serverResult) {      
  document.form1.text1.value = serverResult[0];
  document.form1.text2.value = serverResult[1];
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
text1にB列の値は表示できています。
text2にC列の値を表示したいのです。
変数の受け渡し処理だと思ってますが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど。確認出来る場所にいないので、質問をそのように変更いただけると宜しいかと思います。まず、` return sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      return sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();` の時点で、違和感はありませんか？ 2つの返り値を配列に積んで、それを返せば良いと思いますが。

Comment: 配列に積んで返したところ、正常に機能しました。

Comment: 配列と変数の使い方がいまいちなのです。簡単なことなのでしょうがご提示いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながら、私は user13745 さんが何を知っており、何をイマイチと思っているのか、察することができません。

本件は `google apps script について`の質問でしたので、回答をしたものです。javascript の基本について知りたいのであれば、別途質問を作成されることをオススメします。

とはいえ回答が付くとは限りませんので、 `javascript 入門` などで検索されると宜しいのではないでしょうか。
[初心者のためのJavaScript入門（6）：配列とオブジェクトでデータをまとめる (1/2) - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1011/29/news109.html)